# How to get the comments from a GitHub pull request using GitHub API?

Tags: github-api

I am trying to get the comments on a pull request using GitHub API, for example:

https://api.github.com/repos/mapra99/members-only/pulls/1/comments

But it returns an empty array.

The same if I try to use the `review comments` endpoint:

https://api.github.com/repos/mapra99/members-only/issues/1/comments

Although there is a comment on that pull request:

https://github.com/mapra99/members-only/pull/1

How can I get the comment that is on that pull request using GitHub API? Why is it not possible to get if from any of those endpoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, this is not a comment but a [review](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/) :

> Pull Request Reviews are groups of Pull Request Review Comments on the
>   Pull Request, grouped together with a state and optional body comment.

You can get the reviews using :

https://api.github.com/repos/mapra99/members-only/pulls/1/reviews

Or using [GraphQL v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22mapra99%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22members-only%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pullRequest(number%3A%201)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20reviews(first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20body%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20comments(first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20body%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A) to get reviews & comments :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "mapra99", name: "members-only") {
    pullRequest(number: 1) {
      reviews(first: 100) {
        nodes {
          body
        }
      }
      comments(first: 100) {
        nodes {
          body
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```